# Riemann Mapping theorem doesn't hold true in Several Complex Variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I need to show that Riemann Mapping Theorem is not true in general for $\mathbb{C^n}$. I know Cartan's Uniqueness Theorem and $Aut(B)$ acts transitively on $B$.

But I am unable to deduce the result

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is the statement of the "Riemann Mapping Theorem for $\mathbb{C}^n$" that you wish to disprove?

Comment: @EricWofsey Any simply connected region (not whole $\mathbb{C^n}$) is biholomorphic to the unit ball (Polydisc)?. I am confused on whether it is the polydisc or the unit ball..

Comment: While often one gives the example of polydisc not being equivalent to the ball, it's easier to show that a half-space is not biholomorphic equivalent to any bounded domain: [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362314/biholomorphic-equivalence-in-mathbbcn)

Comment: With that statement, the result is rather trivial (for instance, the complement of a ball is simply connected, but is not even homeomorphic to a ball since it is not contractible).

Comment: How do I show it using Cartan's Uniqueness theorem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automorphism of the bi-disk is $PSU(1,1)^2 \times Z/2Z$, the automorphism of the ball is $PSU(2,1)$. These groups are not the same. In fact if you just know $Aut(B)$, it is enough to check that $PSU(1,1)^2 \subset Aut(B_1^2)$ do not embed in $PSU(2,1)= Aut(B_2)$.